# Is there a chance that emails are sent in parallel and thus `mail.outbox.clear()` doesn't really clear outbox in my django tests?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, python-unittest, django-unittest

I have written django tests to check my outbox emails as shown below

```
class TestX(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # Clear outbox.
        mail.outbox.clear()
        super().setUp()

    def tearDown(self):
        # Clear outbox.
        mail.outbox.clear()
        super().tearDown()
```

however, performing assertions e.g
`self.assertEqual(len(mail.outbox), 1)`
fails with the `len(mail.outbox)` showing a large number as compared to the emails I've sent using send mail. I know there are other apps also sending emails so I'm wondering if the emails are being sent in parallel and thus my `clear` isn't effective or what might be the issue?

Comment: How could we know that?  What is the `mail` object?  How does it get set up?

Comment: By specifying it's django tests I inferred it's a django object but here it is https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/testing/tools/#email-services